# Create Postgresql Default Auto Increment Sequence number based in ID concat with Current Date format

Tags: database, postgresql, sequence

I want to get auto increment default sequence as **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (with 2 digits 'year' format) + ID (5 digits)**...
Like this: 
If current year is **2020**, 
2010001, 2010002, 2010003, ... 
If current year is **2021**, 
2110001, 2110002, 2110003, ... 
Please, help me out, and give me any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal sequence, set its value to 2010000, and at the beginning of 2021 set it to 2110000.

Comment: I tested and it worked like this ... SELECT setval('seq_name', (CAST(TO_CHAR(now(), 'YY') || 10001 AS INTEGER)), FALSE)

Comment: I also thought another way ... Can I create that auto date concat sequence by using trigger for year by year?

Comment: That would be slower, and you still would have to reset the sequence.